# ElasticSearch exception when creating index with mapping(Nest 5.2.0)

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Here I am trying to create a search analyzer in my new index but I get an exception in the **t.Text** "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Nest.dll
Additional information: Could not get field name for TextPropertyDescriptor`1 mapping"

```
        var response = client1.CreateIndex("index", n => n

            .Settings(s => s
                .NumberOfShards(10)
                .NumberOfReplicas(10)
                .Analysis(a => a
                              .TokenFilters(af=>af.EdgeNGram("autocompletefilter",e=>e.MinGram(1)
                                                                                       .MaxGram(20)))
                              .Analyzers(an => an.Custom("autocomplete", ana => ana.Tokenizer("standard")
                                                                            .Filters("lowercase", "asciifolding", "standard")))))
            .Mappings(m=>m.Map("mytype",my=>my.Properties(t=>t.Text(te=>te.Analyzer("autocomplete")
                                                                           .SearchAnalyzer("standard"))))));
```

Comment: You defined property without any name. Try `te => te.Name("name").Analyzer(..)`.

Comment: Also, 10 replicas means 10 **sets** of replica shards of the 10 primary shards i.e. 100 shards. This is likely too many replicas (unless you're running a very large cluster), so consider reducing this

Comment: Thank you for your help.Now I am trying to search in the index, but I cant use analyzer, I get as exception "request [/index/mytype/_search] contains unrecognized parameter: [analyzer]"

Comment: @grlouk consider opening a new question about the analyzer with all the details needed to replicate the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it needs

```
      te => te.Name("name").Analyzer(..)
```